# Enabling the Asynchronous Server API in OpenAPI generated code for Jersey on demand

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, openapi-generator

We are using OpenAPI via gradle (i.e. *openapi-generator-gradle-plugin*) for generating Jersey resources. Generally speaking this works fine.

The generated methods look like this:

```
public Response getSomeFoo(@ApiParam(...) String someParam, ...) { ...
```

But we would also like to support methods that use the [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e9895).

In theory we could change all the generated synchronous methods to asynchronous ones, namely adapting the template files `api.mustache` and `apiService.mustache` where we replace the `Response` by `void` and adding the `@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse` as first parameter (plus adding the imports etc.).

But it does not make sense for us to convert **all** the requests from being processed synchronously to asynchronously.

So my question is: How can we achieve some kind of "switch" to indicate in the input file already what kind of implementation we want to generate (synchronously/asynchronously) for each method?

I was thinking of writing a new generator that reads in a e.g. a tag from the input spec file and puts this into a boolean variable which is evaluated in the template files. Is this feasible? Is there any similar issue solved already? Or do you have any other ideas for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution myself now which is luckily quite handy: OpenAPI provides us with [Extensions](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating#extensions) – one of which I used in order to solve the issue. I use my custom `x-async-enabled` extension in the spec JSON as follows:

```
"paths": {
   "/fubaz": {
     "get": {
       "summary": "My Fubaz resource",
       "operationId": "fubaz",
       "x-async-enabled": true,
 ...
```

And then I use this information in the template in order to conditionally generate a different signature for the respective methods (file `api.mustache`):

```
{{#operation}}
    public {{#vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}void{{/vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}{{^vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}Response{{/vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}} {{nickname}}({{#vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, {{/vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}{{#allParams}}{{>queryParams}}{{>pathParams}}{{>headerParams}}{{>bodyParams}}{{>formParams}},{{/allParams}})
    throws Exception {
        {{#vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}
            delegate.{{nickname}}(asyncResponse, {{#allParams}}{{#isFormParam}}{{#isFile}}{{paramName}}InputStream, {{paramName}}Detail{{/isFile}}{{/isFormParam}}{{^isFile}}{{paramName}}{{/isFile}}{{^isFormParam}}{{#isFile}}{{paramName}}{{/isFile}}{{/isFormParam}}, {{/allParams}});
        {{/vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}
        {{^vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}
            return delegate.{{nickname}}({{#allParams}}{{#isFormParam}}{{#isFile}}{{paramName}}InputStream, {{paramName}}Detail{{/isFile}}{{/isFormParam}}{{^isFile}}{{paramName}}{{/isFile}}{{^isFormParam}}{{#isFile}}{{paramName}}{{/isFile}}{{/isFormParam}}, {{/allParams}});
        {{/vendorExtensions.x-async-enabled}}
    }
{{/operation}}
```

Of course I also had to adapt the imports and to do the basically same thing also in `apiService.mustache`. That did the trick for me and I can now just simply mark what I want to handle with the Asynchronous Server API.